# Confirm if two expressions refer to the same MS Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a MS Word (2016) subroutine (macro), I am trying to confirm if a table containing the current user selection on a subsequent macro call is the same table as the one selected on a previous call and preserved in static variables.

I confirm that the selection is within a table using `.Information` and have saved the previous table as a Variant object `Set Tbl1 = Selection.Tables(1)`. However, when I try to test if the second table is the same object using `Tbl1 Is Tbl2`, the result is `False` even when the tables are known to be the same and no other changes have occurred to the document.

Moreover, even (in a document containing several tables) the test `ActiveDocument.Tables(1) Is ActiveDocument.Tables(1)` results in `False`, when I would expect these to be exactly the same Object. Compare Excel `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1) Is ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` which is `True`.

Can anyone explain this (or reveal the error in my test)?

I could solve my identification problem by, eg, comparing some table content or feature, but this is unreliable (due to possible replication in another table), or by uniquely setting an often unused table property, eg, `.Descr` or `.Title`, or by wrapping the table in a Bookmark (which is at least uniquely identifiable by its `.Name`, though Bookmarks, too, fail the `Is` test above), but I would rather not have to modify the table or the document simply in order to do the test. I could also compare the table locations, eg, by `Tbl1.Range.Start`, but this also could be unreliable if the document has been modified between selections/calls. Any other suggestions? Does Word not have any kind of unique table identifier/property?

**Added background:-**

I frequently have long Word tables (maybe over several pages) in which I have merged (some) cells horizontally and/or vertically. If I later need to change the width of a 'notional' column, this can be very tedious, especially if several shorter tables have been joined and the notional columns don't even align. **NB** I appreciate that Word doesn't preserve any understanding of the uniform, rectangular column structure that would have existed before any merging - a 'merged' cell is just another cell, and a 'merged' table simply has varying numbers of odd-sized cells ('columns') per row; and it's even messier with vertical merging.

Even though Word has a nice facility to click & drag a left/right cell boundary, and all cell 'columns' with the same position will move together, this is awkward to use successfully on long tables, especial if they have similar but not identical cell boundaries. So I wanted to write a macro that would let me pre-set desired boundaries for 'notional' columns (eg, using the widths of a reference row having the maximum number of cells) and apply them to the whole table, making allowance for 'merged' cells that appeared to span more than one of these reference row columns. I anticipated that I might not find a fully successful algorithm for doing this and that I might keep having to relinquish control to the user to manually adjust 'awkward' rows and then restart the automatic process. Hence the need to verify that, when the macro is re-called, the same table is being worked on (even though some aspects of it have changed).

There are several ways round this identification problem that are probably good enough in practice (eg, based on range start/end points, etc) but I was intrigued that my initial supposition that I would be able to compare Table objects directly (as I thought I could in Excel) didn't seem to work in Word. I am surprised that a Word table doesn't seem to maintain an 'identity' that survives document editing, either inside or outside the table.

**Further Info:-**

In Excel, where cell D6 is within a table and is selected:
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1) Is ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` -> **true**;
`Range("D6").ListObject Is Range("D6").ListObject` -> false;
`Selection.ListObject Is Selection.ListObject` -> false.

So, even here, some 'derived' objects (eg, table from cell or selection) do not seem to be exactly equivalent even though they purport to represent the same entity on the worksheet. *It would still be nice to have some technical explanation for these phenomena, if anyone can oblige*, but it seems clear that I cannot just compare objects using `Is` in the way I was hoping.

Comment: That is definitely strange.  If you compare the start and end values for the table ranges they are definitely the same when referring to ActiveDocument.tables(1)

Comment: If you store a reference to a table range this will update in line with any editing done to the table.

Comment: @freeflow But `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range Is ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range` is also `False`. So, although your first comment is true, storing the `Table.Range` object doesn't help me because its start and/or end still won't compare with the second table if editing has occurred, and the range objects can't be directly compared. I'm beginning to think that maybe (some?) Word objects are not 'proper' objects at all, even though that's what they are called in MS documentation? Perhaps each reference creates a new instance of the class, even though it has indentical properties - but why??

Comment: @fleeflow I can see why deriving a table reference from a user selection might be grounds for creating a new instance which may have identical properties to an earlier version, but is still not 'technically' the same object. But why shouldn't ActiveDocument.Tables(1) always produce the same object when the document hasn't changed? Obviously, editing the document could mean than another table becomes #1, but surely the Tables collection is just a list of pointers that is easily reordered as the document changes?

Comment: There appears to be some confusion about what you mean by same table. Based on your later comments it seems that you are referring to table content rather that position in the word document. If that is the case then your use of ranges is doomed to failure. Instead you should focus on capturing the text of a table range and checking that rather than the range itself.

Comment: @freeflow I didn't express myself carefully enough - I've added a fuller explanation to the original question

Comment: @NickC If you keep your question short and focused, then you will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Tables` collection does not keep a list of pointers based on the result of running this sub:

```
Sub GetTablesPointer()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Tables.Count
        Debug.Print ObjPtr(ThisDocument.Tables(i))
    Next i
    Debug.Print "========="
End Sub
```

Running the above sub twice on the same document that has 4 tables return a result which is puzzling since the pointers are totally different despite no changes has been made:

```
 1440600498992 
 1440600502352 
 1440600503472 
 1440600499440 
=========
 1439972070768 
 1439972068416 
 1439972065616 
 1439972066624 
=========
```

Using `InRange` method, below sub will work as long as the table previously called is not moved/cut-paste onto other part of the document  (which in this case, will return `Error 5825 - Object has been deleted` that I suppose you can make a handler for this scenario):

```
Sub Test()
    Static wdTable As Table
    
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        If wdTable Is Nothing Then
            Set wdTable = Selection.Tables(1)
        Else
            If Selection.Range.InRange(wdTable.Range) Then
                Debug.Print "Same table"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Different table"
                Set wdTable = Selection.Tables(1)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is interesting that the pointers change without underlying change to the document. Maybe there is 'housekeeping' that occurs silently in the background that causes things to move around in memory whilst still preserving document functionality? I have tried the same thing in Excel and the pointers to two different tables remain the same on subsequent calls - but this is consistent with `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` equating 'properly' with itself. I have added some more background information to the original question.